# Cant understand a function of tic tac toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function is suppose to check for a winner/loser/draw in a tic tac toe game

Can some explain what is going on in this function?

```
def check(grid):
for i in range(0,3):
    row = set([grid[i][0],grid[i][1],grid[i][2]])
    if len(row) == 1 and grid[i][0] != 0:
        return grid[i][0]

for i in range(0,3):
    column = set([grid[0][i],grid[1][i],grid[2][i]])
    if len(column) == 1 and grid[0][i] != 0:
        return grid[0][i]

diag1 = set([grid[0][0],grid[1][1],grid[2][2]])
diag2 = set([grid[0][2],grid[1][1],grid[2][0]])

if len(diag1) == 1 or len(diag2) == 1 and grid[1][1] != 0:
    return grid[1][1]
return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`set` basically removes duplicates from lists. In this case, `set` is used with `len` to determine if the list consists of only one number, which sees if someone has filled a row, column or diagonal.